# Delete from a Ruby Hash, returning the value and raising an exception if the key is not found

Tags: ruby, hash

How can I **delete** a value from a Hash in Ruby, returning the deleted value, but raise an exception if the requested key is not found?

I'm looking for something that combines the functionality of `#fetch` and `#delete`:

```
the_hash = { foo: "bar", fizz: "buzz" }

# Expected
the_hash.fetch(:not_foo)
# => KeyError: key not found: :not_foo

# Not expected
the_hash.fetch(:foo)
# => Does not delete

# Expected
the_hash.delete(:foo)
the_hash # => { fizz: "buzz" }

# Not expected
the_hash.delete(:not_fizz)
# => nil # I want to raise an exception.
```

Example method; this doesn't really exist.

```
the_hash.delete!(:not_buzz)
# => KeyError: key not found: :not_buzz

the_hash.delete!(:fizz)
# => Deletes.
```

Is there anything like my fake method `delete!`? Or am I going to have to do it in multiple lines?

(I know that in most cases it would be redundant to check that the key is there when I'm going to delete it anyway, but it applies in my case, I can't be bothered to write out the full explanation but just trust me.)

Comment: `the_hash.fetch(:not_foo); the_hash.delete(:not_fizz)` is too long for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it in one method, I think you need to create it.

```
class Hash
  def delete! key; fetch(key); delete(key) end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

a more idiomatic way would be to pass the optional block which is used when the key is not found:

```
[1] pry(main)> {}.delete(:foo) { |k| fail KeyError, k }
KeyError: foo
```

You could of course use `.fetch` in delete's block to get the normal `KeyError` message

```
[2] pry(main)> h = {}; h.delete(:foo) { |k| h.fetch(k) }
KeyError: key not found: :foo
```

Docs: [Hash#delete](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-delete)